# C# invoke goes bad

Tags: c#, invoke

ListBox is a listbox
ServerClient is an instance of a class which has arraylist

```
Arraylist pclist = new Arraylist();
```

temping is array of strings as

```
strings[] temping = new string[6];
```

Now, during execution... The error I get is:
"Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
this.ListBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ServerClient.pclist.Count; i++)
    {
        // I am Alive,MyPcName,192.168.1.1,Status,NickName,datetime
        temp = ServerClient.pclist[i].ToString();
        temping = temp.Split(',');

        ListBox.Items.Add(temping[4] + "( " + temping[3] + " )");
    }

    for (int i = ServerClient.pclist.Count; i < ListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}));
```

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: if I were you I'd debug each line inside that delegate.. to see which line has that Object which isn't set?. This is one of those errors that's very common.. when some control isn't initialized.. You can see which one is `null` in local variables, if not.. it could be nested inside like pclist

Comment: exception was on complete invoke

Comment: Visual Studio should be able to tell you in the debugger which object is null. When you get the exception, go to Debug > Window > Autos, and see which one is 'null'.

Comment: @SSpoke, Thanks for advice.... I am looking into it now....

Comment: guys, I am debugging it, but I am unable to understand what the hell is null there.... My debugg fails at this point of code temping = temp.Split(',');

Comment: If it fails there it can only be temp that is null.

Comment: Probably have to place `strings[] temping;` inside the delegate, might fix it all.

Comment: temp cannot be null.  Beware that the green execution indicator points to the line *after* the one that bombs.  Most likely pclist contains a null.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd split my Invoke function up so that the called delegate function is declared elsewhere. Having an inline function declaration like this can be bad enough to debug, but a delegate is doubly so.

I think that you'll find that by declaring your in line function in this way the compiler is assigning all variables as locals, which won't have been intialised before use.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove items with RemoveAt in the last loop you have to go down instead of up, because the index of the last item decreases everytime you remove an item with RemoveAt. If you loop down this won't affect the outcome:

```
for (int i = ListBox.Items.Count - 1; i >= ServerClient.pclist.Count; i--)
{
    ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```